# Vue.js closes form tag in a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue.js to create a table in which every row is form with a submit button, this is the code I use:

```
  <div id="admin-user">
    <table class="table">
      <tr v-for="(user, index) in users">
        <form action="/ajax/submit/admin/user.php">
          <td class="spacer"><input type="text" class="form-control" :value="user.id" readonly></td>
          <td class="spacer"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" :value="user.fullname"></td>
          <td class="spacer"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" :value="user.username"></td>
          <td class="spacer"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" :value="user.email"></td>
          <td class="spacer"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" :value="user.phone"></td>
          <td class="spacer"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" :value="user.company"></td>

          <input type="hidden" name="id" :value="user.id">
          <td class="spacer"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg right"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Of course I also have the Vue.js code in JavaScript but I don't think its necessary to solve this problem and it is quite long so I wont bother anyone with it.
The styling turns out fine but the form doesn't work, so I took a look with the inspector tool and this is what I found

[image: Google Chrome HTML inspector picture]

And it turns out the `</form>` tag got closed prematurely. I don't understand why this happend which also means I don't know how to solve it. I hope someone could explain why this is happening to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not because of Vue.js or even Javascript, the problem is because of HTML itself. HTML does not allow the use of a form tag directly inside a table (row). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249688/html-is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-tag-in-each-table-row-in-a-xhtml-valid-way) which has some working solutions.