# <div> tag closing prematurely in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having some problems with my html page in django
This is the part of the page im having problem with :

```
<form method="post" action="">
               <div data-prefill-targets-for="1">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {% for group in grouped_fields  %}
                  
                  <tr>
                     {% cycle 'bgcolor1' 'bgcolor2' as row_color silent %}
                     {% for field in group reversed%}
                     {% cycle 'bgcolor1' 'bgcolor2' as cell_color silent %}
                     {% if forloop.first %}
                     <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">
                        {{ field }}
                     </td>
                     {% else %}
                     <td class="w-11 text-center {{ cell_color }}">
                        {{ field }}
                        <br>
                        <span>xx</span>
                     </td>
                     {% if forloop.last %}
                     <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">اول</td>
                     {% endif %}
                     {% endif %}
                     {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </form>
```

as you can see I have opened  and then closed the div at last line just before

But in page view :

```
<div data-prefill-targets-for="1">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="2VEsmoNuXje9U9ie4aXGo74ObmD6d6I0WKGSg845XaObSYlTKz9qrkWQrFejAFkB">
  </div>
```

it closes itself right after csrf token and doesnt contain rest of my form.
this is driving me crazy I dont understand where I went wrong.

just FYI this is the only JS code I have running on my page :

```
function handlePrefillForBoundTarget(evt) {
    const targetRoot = this;
    const emptyPrefillTarget = Array
      .from(
        targetRoot
          .querySelectorAll('[data-prefill-target]')
      )
      .filter(elmNode =>
        (elmNode.value?.trim?.() ?? elmNode.value) === ''
      )[0];
  
    if (emptyPrefillTarget) {
      const prefillSource = evt
        .target
        .closest('[data-prefill-value]');
  
      const { prefillValue } = prefillSource.dataset;
  
      emptyPrefillTarget.value = prefillValue;
    }
  }
  
  function initPrefillComponent(sourceRoot) {
    const componentId = sourceRoot
      .dataset
      .prefillValuesFor ?? '';
  
    const targetRoot = document
      .querySelector(`[data-prefill-targets-for="${ componentId }"]`);
  
    if (targetRoot) {
      sourceRoot
        .addEventListener(
          'click',
          handlePrefillForBoundTarget
            .bind(targetRoot)
        );
    }
  }
  
  function main() {
    document
      .querySelectorAll('[data-prefill-values-for]')
      .forEach(initPrefillComponent);
  }
  main();
```

Edit:
I included the entire page for refrence

```
{%load static%}
{% load custom_filters %}
<html dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
      <title>عنوان</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="nav">
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">صفحه اصلی</a>
            </li>
            <li id="srinpt">
               <span>
               <input />
               </span>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="big-header">
         کـــارت نـــوبـــت
      </div>
      <div class="light-header">
         شماره ثبت کتابخانه ملی جمهوری اسالمی ایران44311و
      </div>
      <div class="light-header">
         واحد ثبت آثار ، سند شماره78/3413و/33تاریخ4378/53/57ساعت33:43
      </div>
      <div class="dark-bg">
         درجدول زیرهردوحرفی ، عددی2رقمی است ،7دوحرفی با ترتیب انتخاب شما درجدول زیر ثبت می شود
      </div>
      <div data-prefill-values-for="1">
         <div id="darkbox" class="dark-bg">
            {% for item in cartitems reversed %}
            <div class="darkbox_item dark-bg">
               <button data-prefill-value="{{item}}">{{item}}</button>
            </div>
            {%endfor%}
         </div>
      </div>
      <table id="tbl1">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="w-12 bgcolor2 text-center">
                  از 0 تا 9 یک عدد انتخاب کن
               </td>
               <td class="w-11 text-center bgcolor1">
                  y
                  <br>
                  x
               </td>
               <td class="w-11 text-center bgcolor1">
                  =
                  <br>
                  =
               </td>
               <td colspan="5" class="w-11 text-center bgcolor1">
                  هفت دو حرفی انتخاب شده شما
                  <br>
                  عدد 14 رقمی نوبت شما
               </td>
               <td class="w-12 bigcell bgcolor2">نَفَر</td>
            </tr>
            
            <form method="post" action="">
               <div data-prefill-targets-for="1">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {% for group in grouped_fields  %}
                  
                  <tr>
                     {% cycle 'bgcolor1' 'bgcolor2' as row_color silent %}
                     {% for field in group reversed%}
                     {% cycle 'bgcolor1' 'bgcolor2' as cell_color silent %}
                     {% if forloop.first %}
                     <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">
                        {{ field }}
                     </td>
                     {% else %}
                     <td class="w-11 text-center {{ cell_color }}">
                        {{ field }}
                        <br>
                        <span>xx</span>
                     </td>
                     {% if forloop.last %}
                     <td class="w-12 bigcell {{ row_color }}">اول</td>
                     {% endif %}
                     {% endif %}
                     {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </form>
   </body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/valuereplace.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: That HTML structure doesn't make sense.  Where do your `<table>` and `<tbody>` begin?  Things like `<form>` and `<div>` can't be a child of things like `<tbody>`, only `<tr>` can.

Comment: @David I included the entire HTML page for reference at the bottom of my question

Comment: That's the problem then, your HTML is invalid.  (1) You're trying to overlap elements, which can't be done.  Elements are always entirely nested.  (2) `<form>` and `<div>` can not be between `<tbody>` and `<tr>` in a table structure.  Either the entire table is wrapped in a form, or a single cell contains a form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)  Or this? [HTML: Is it possible to have a FORM tag in each TABLE ROW in a XHTML valid way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249688/html-is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-tag-in-each-table-row-in-a-xhtml-valid-way)

Comment: @David Thanks for your reply.so how should I approach editing my html with your given answer?

Comment: If your goal is to wrap the entire table with a single `<form>` then wrap the whole table with that `<form>`, not just the contents of the `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you open the div inside the  but you are closing it after the  so html is infering where it should place the  tag since the one you placed is out of its scope. Try moving the  inside the  tag or bring the  and  tags after the